# How to count the sum of the value and put it as other MySQL Join

Tags: mysql

I have a 2 table that i join

the first table was the course

[image]

the second one is the attendance

[image]

i tried this query bellow

[image]

what i want to happen is that every attendance(attendance_course) that is not correspond to the course(course) will count as a Other

just like the example data in attendance the value 'love' should be count as 1 in other

'NOT WITH ROLL UP TOTAL'

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Errr, you gave the answer yourself ^^

You just need to solve the ambiguity created like so :

```
SELECT ifnull(course.Course,'Other') as course, count(attendance_course) as total...
```

If your left join return `NULL`, then it's a `Other` category. The total's total should be treated separately.

Now, as an advice, if you're in position to enforce changes in the DB, you should join `course` and `attendance` with the `course_id` (instead of a name), and add a `denomination` column in attendance IF you wish to specify an "`attendance_course` name" different from the `course` name.